# Best way to fix gate post over foundation that extends

Tags: foundation, brick, gate-post

1930s brick house.

Foundation at ground level extends 8 inches out.

Want to put a 3.5 x 3.5 post right next to the wall and have these ideas(post will have gate latch):

1. Build a form next to wall that extends over edge of foundation.  Think upside L.  Cons: lots of concrete. Pros: ?
2. Affix anchor on foundation, affix post to anchor.  Cons: weak?  Rust?  Pros: probably best looking
3. Affix post directly to wall.  Cons: weaken wall?  Pros: ?
4. ?

I'm thinking this community will go with 2, but I'd like to hear your thoughts on whatever you think would be the best way.

Comment: The post won’t weaken the wall if you find a stud and tie in there I have done this many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common where I come from (New Zealand) to [Dynabolt](https://ramset.co.nz/Product/Detail/82/DynaBolt-Plus-Sleeve-Anchors) the gate or fence post directly to a brick, block or rendered wall.

I have about 4 of them in various places around my 1960's render over concrete block house

As long as the size of the Dynabolt is appropriate there should be no significant weakening of the brick(s) you drill into. There are variations of these Dynabolts that are chem-set into the wall/brick/block with Epoxy, one of these would in theory further reduce any negliable impact in the integrity of the brick.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into us equivalent.

Comment: Dynabolt is a name-brand sleeve anchor (trademark of Ramset ITW).  It's very well respected in New Zealand and Australia.

Comment: @[Chris Butler] thx again, just bolted it on today with "red head" type 3/8 anchors.  Actually seems it will be stronger in an earthquake.

Comment: Legend, glad it worked out! Actually realized after my original post that I also have a gazebo header bar dynabolted or anchor bolted to the side of my block garage as well!